# Rename [vscode-extensions] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [vscode-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions) tag seems to be misused for extension *usage* rather than *development* more often than not. Here's just three recent examples (from which I already removed the tag):

- [Visual Studio Code (ctrl+E in Brackets) where is this shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783127/visual-studio-code-ctrle-in-brackets-where-is-this-shortcut)
- [React DOM not updating after the browser/react server stopped supporting a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771081/react-not-working-after-using-debugger-for-chrome-in-vscode)
- [Prettier is not indenting as specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763503/prettier-is-not-indenting-as-specified)

The tag wiki is already quite explicit about this:

> Questions about the Visual Studio Code (VSCode) Extension API and extension development. Questions about extension usage should use tag [visual-studio-code]

However, unsurprisingly that doesn't help much. It doesn't help that there's a similar tag [visual-studio-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-extensions) which *does* seem to be ok to use for extension usage.

I'd suggest renaming the tag to something that makes it immediately clear that it's for extension development specifically, such as [vscode-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-api), which now has some questions but no tag guidance.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: I mean.. it kind of defeats the point of a tag, if it's not used for its intended purpose? Alternatively, the tag wiki should be changed.

Comment: I think the tag wiki should be changed. There's no real reason for the distinction, imho. I don't think it's confusing, at least, to find questions about using extensions and questions about creating extensions in the same tag...

Comment: I think it's useful to have be able to filter for questions related to extension development - questions about extension _usage_ are usually quite different. There's similar tags for other editors, such as [sublime-text-plugin], [intellij-plugin] or [eclipse-plugin], which all appear to be limited to plugin _development_.

Answer (score 1):

**I'd propose to rename it to `vscode-extension-development` over `vscode-api`.** As far as I know, the VS Code API is expressly for extension development (and nothing else). From [the API doc page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api):

> VS Code API is a set of JavaScript APIs that you can invoke in your Visual Studio Code extension. This page lists all VS Code APIs available to extension authors.

That is to say, questions about the (extension) API are topically a subset of the topic of extension development, and there is more to VS Code extension development than usage of the VS Code API.

#### An idea of the scale of this problem

It would really *really* be nice to get this rename done. I've seen poor [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) doing *many* a tag edit to fix this common misconception of this tag's purpose. At the time of this writing, it's [**1409 times according to my SEDE query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1774383/number-of-times-riov8-has-edited-out-the-vscode-extensions-tag). *Just by rioV8 alone.* If you query for such edits by anyone, then that totals up to [**3575**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1774385/number-of-times-the-vscode-extensions-tag-has-been-edited-out). For reference, the [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) tag has 56206 at the time of this writing, and the [vscode-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions) tag has 4191 questions. So of just non-deleted questions, the number of times this tag has been edited out so far is approximately **85.3%** of the number of times it has been used properly.